# Indentation of UITableViewCell changes after rotation only on iOS 8

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios8, orientation

I have an `UITableView` with three dynamic rows. When displaying the `UITableViewController` the first time everything works fine. After a rotation the rows which have a data in it get an indentation despite I set `setLayoutMargins` to zero. I cannot reproduce this issue in another project until now. It is only appearing in iOS 8 but but only on one table. The same source for the table is working in a test project without problems. The only difference here is that it is in a container with some other views.

I checked auto layout constraints, the rotation methods, commented things out - all without success. The change of the indentation occurs between `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` and `didRotateToInterfaceOrientation` or after `viewWillTransitionToSize`. I even updated to iOS 8.1 with the same results.

Has someone expeerienced a similar behavior?

PS:
What I've also noticed that when setting the layout margins to zero on iOS 8 the animation is not as smooth as it would be with the default values (with indentation). On iOS 7 the animation is always smooth.

**EDIT:**

I tracked some things down. If a `UITableViewController` is embedded into an `UINavigationController` the indentation happens on rotation. If you rotate further it goes back to it's set indentation (no indentation in my case).

If the `UITableViewController` is embedded into a container (and this container is in a navigation controller) than after the rotation the cell get it's default indentation back. If you rotate further this behavior stays the same (always indented).

Are some events not send to the child view controller or none of you uses a `UITableViewController` embedded into an `UINavigationController`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion it is a iOS 8 Bug or a Xamarin Bug. Perhaps one other could verify if it is the same with his installation. I'm using Xamarin Studio 5.5.2 with Xcode 6.1.

One ugly solution to this is this:

```
public override void DidRotate (UIInterfaceOrientation fromInterfaceOrientation)
{
    base.DidRotate (fromInterfaceOrientation);

    // otherwise cells are indented! iOS 8 Bug?
    TableView.ReloadData ();
}
```

One could use `reloadData` or `reloadSection` in `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation`, despite it is a deprecated function. But there is no `viewDidTransitionToSize` and I also have to support iOS 7.

**Edit:**

Another solution I have come up with is to draw a custom separator line. This only works for iOS 8 and would answer the question (despite I've another issue on iOS 7 where this approach doesn't help).